# Изменить поведение print в python > 3.3

Tags: python-3.x

Требуется изменить поведение встроенной функции "print" с тем чтобы каждый результат её вызова в любом месте программы не приводил к переводу строки. К примеру:

```
print("One")
print("Two")
```

Должно в результате выдать

```
OneTwo
```

но никак не

```
One
Two
```

З.Ы.
Восточная мудрость: минусуя вопросы, которые вам непонятны – себе понимания не добавите :)

Comment: Если несложный вопрос и вам известно решение - зачем спрашиваете ?

Comment: Считайте это чем то вроде конкурса :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С учётом правки *An0ther0ne*

```
pprint = print
print = lambda *args, **kwargs: pprint(end='', *args, **kwargs)
print("One")
print("Two","Tree", sep=", ")
```

Comment: Хм. А это уже чтото новенькое. Вот почему  я собственно и задавал вопрос на который знал ответ. Хотелось увидеть более элегантное решение :)

Comment: Однако Ваше решение при всей простоте (что безусловно преимущество) не лишено недостатков: в функцию принт нельзя передать больше одного параметра...

Comment: Теперь можно...

Comment: А почему бы просто немного не подправить Вашу предыдущую версию, например вот так:
    pprint = print
    print = lambda *args, **kwargs: pprint(end='', *args, **kwargs)
    print("One")
    print("Two","Tree",sep=", ")

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы ожидаете в качестве решения что-то подобное:

```
from functools import partial
print = partial(print, end='')

print("One")
print("Two")
```

Результат:

```
OneTwo
```

Обновление:

Решение с использованием декоратора, может выглядеть так:

```
def wrap_print(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['end'] = ''
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

print = wrap_print(print)

print("One")
print("Two")
```

Результат:

```
OneTwo
```

Comment: В принципе всё верно (плюсик Вам в карму). А теперь бонусный вопрос: как решить эту задачу без импорта?

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, спасибо :)